# Is that possible using queryDSL?

Tags: jpql, querydsl

There are two entities A and B relate one to many.

[image]

I want to extract "B_2" with there parent("A_1") and children("B_1", "B_2", "B_3") of there parent. So I try my code below.

```
from(QB.b).join(QB.b.a, QA.a).fetch().join(QA.a.bList).fetch().where(QB.b.name.eq("B_2"));
```

But result B.a.bList are just proxy object. And it occur to N+1 problem. 
Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this example, let's called the Querydsl query types for entity A `a` and for entity B `b`.

```
.from(a)
.innerJoin(b)
.on(a.a_id).eq(b.a_id)
.where(b.name.eq("B_2"))
.fetch();
```